# How to use the sound output to create a javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, text-to-speech

I'm trying to recreate Karen from the Spongebob. To do so, I need to make a canvas that react to the sound that the browser itself emits (using `SpeechSunthesisUtterance`). The only problem is: the canvas only react if I use a loaded audio, but not a real output.

I searched how to build a soundwave using JS and how to get the sound output, but I acutally don't know exacly how it works.

**The JS:**

```
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
let audio = document.getElementById("Audio");

const streamDestination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
const mediaStream = streamDestination.stream;

const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
mediaRecorder.start();

analyser.connect(streamDestination);

analyser.fftSize = 2048;
const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

// Capturing the canvas
let canvas = document.getElementById("waves-canvas");

// Configuring the canvas
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;
let wid = canvas.width;
let hei = canvas.height;

// Define the width of each segment based in the fftSize
let sliceWidth = (wid * 1.0) / bufferLength;
// CONFIGURANDO ESTILO DO CANVAS
canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, wid, hei);
canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#151515";
// Line style
canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb(249, 251, 250)";
canvasCtx.shadowOffsetX = 1;
canvasCtx.shadowOffsetY = 1;
canvasCtx.shadowBlur = 10;
canvasCtx.shadowColor = "rgb(28, 213, 254)";

function drawCanvas() {
  const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

  canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
  canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
  canvasCtx.beginPath();

  const sliceWidth = (canvas.width * 1.0) / bufferLength;
  let x = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
    const v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
    const y = (v * canvas.height) / 2;

    if (i === 0) {
      canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
    } else {
      canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    x += sliceWidth;
  }

  canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
  canvasCtx.stroke();

  requestAnimationFrame(drawCanvas);
}

drawCanvas();

//var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
//msg.text = "Test of speech";
//window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Karen</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <audio id="Audio" controls>
      <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio> -->

    <div class="waves-container">
      <canvas id="waves-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no built-in way to hook on the output of the browser's TTS. The only hackish way I'm aware of consists in installing a virtual audio device on your system (e.g [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/) might do, though I didn't try it in a long time) with one input and one output (or more), plug your default audio output to that virtual device's input, and then select its output as source in `getUserMedia({ audio: true })`

Comment: I think that using the user input will be the best way. Thank you for your time.